# Method 'POST' is not supported error. Using PATCH method with Thymeleaf. The hiddenHttpMethodFilter doesn`t work for me in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am very new in Java Spring and I`m learning it now. I try to update my simple like "Hello World" Spring MVC application. This is not a Spring Boot app. That is why there is no application.settings file in the project.resources folder (but actually resources is not a folder - it is link to a settings of the project, where I couldn't find solution of the problem). So, when I run this app and open edit.html page with form where th:method="PATCH" parameter used, I get the error above.

The code of the edit.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Update Person</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- we have to use 'th:' because standard formatting does not support PATCH method (only GET and POST) -->
<form th:method="PATCH" th:action="@{/people/{id}(id=${person.getId()})}" th:object="${person}">
  <label for="name">Enter name: </label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Update!"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The controller methods:

```
// Open page to edit person`s fields
@GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
public String edit(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    // to edit data, we better see what we will edit:
    model.addAttribute("person", personDAO.show(id));
    return "people/edit";
}

// by method PATCH from edit form we get object Person to update person`s data by id
@PatchMapping("/{id}")
public String update(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
    personDAO.update(id, person);
    return "redirect:/people";
}
```

And I use code below in my public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer witch extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class to allow hidden http methods:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(aServletContext);
    registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);
}

private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
    aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
    new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
}
```

I use dependency of jakarta, because javax doesn't work anymore:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I want to use PATCH, DELETE methods in my html file, but as I see that the program does not recognize that I trying to allow hidden filter (code above).

Project structure is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbwf8.png)

I was looking for this problem in the forum and the Internet. But everywhere people talk about Spring Boot (in my case it is not - it is simple web app using Spring MVC structure) and application.settings file. What is wrong in my case?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: "because javax doesn't work anymore" -  it's not true. You can use javax.servlet-api 4.0.1 without any problems.

It looks like all you've done all things to use PATCH.
Try to clean MAVEN (look at the screenshot) and restart your server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkJ6L.png)

Comment: Yes. After cleaning Maven Lifecilcle it normal works. I found the solution after more deep digging the Internet. Thank you! PS. So it`s very strange that it is not documented anywhere.